# Gitlab CI on Kubernetes Cluster (Openstack)

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, openstack, gitlab-ci, kubectl

I am trying to follow this short doc about how to use Gitlab CI with a Kubernetes Cluster that I am creating with Openstack: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html

I manage to create it but any time I create the ConfigMap and Deployment as specified in the previous link the pods it creates are stuck in a CrashLoopBackOff like this:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                            READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
gitlab        gitlab-runner-3998042981-f8dlh                  0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   36         2h
gitlab        gitlab-runner-3998042981-g9m5g                  0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   36         2h
gitlab        gitlab-runner-3998042981-q0bth                  0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   36         2h
gitlab        gitlab-runner-3998042981-rjztk                  0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   36         2h
kube-system   coredns-1977636023-1q47s                        1/1       Running            0          21h
kube-system   grafana-1173934969-vw49f                        1/1       Running            0          21h
kube-system   node-exporter-gitlab-ci-hc6k3ffax54o-minion-0   1/1       Running            0          21h
kube-system   node-exporter-gitlab-ci-hc6k3ffax54o-minion-1   1/1       Running            0          21h
kube-system   prometheus-873144915-s9m6j                      1/1       Running            0          21h
```

My problem is that I am not able to know why this happens since pod logs are not available when they are not created.

Apart from that I just do not know what to do with the specified volumes since I just think this has some relation with the crashloops.

Deployment specifies:

```
- configMap:
      name: gitlab-runner
    name: config
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla
    name: cacerts
```

I have found that:

> A hostPath volume mounts a file or directory from the host node’s
>   filesystem into your pod

After running the pods without the cacerts volume everything is created but afterwards no job will be executed.

Log from any pod:

```
Starting multi-runner from /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml ...  builds=0
Running in system-mode.

Configuration loaded                                builds=0
Metrics server disabled
ERROR: Checking for jobs... forbidden               runner=<PARTOFTHETOKEN>
ERROR: Checking for jobs... forbidden               runner=<PARTOFTHETOKEN>
ERROR: Checking for jobs... forbidden               runner=<PARTOFTHETOKEN>
ERROR: Runner https://URL/ci<TOKEN> is not healthy and will be disabled!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actual docs about having Gitlab CI running on a kubernetes cluster are not clear enough.

You need to run somewhere gitlab-runner register with the token you get from the Runner's admin page of your Gitlab instance and grab another token from resulting config (cat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml | grep token) and paste it into your deployment config so it can now receive jobs from CI.

> UPDATE 2019: gitlab.com docs now make it clear:
>   https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/#gnulinux